# How can I stop the Phonograph reindex job from running automatically when the backing dataset builds?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

I've registered a dataset as an input dataset with Phonograph. Whenever I build the dataset, a Phonograph reindex job is kicked off. Is there any way to disable this automatic sync?

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed by design. The Phonograph table is meant to always reflect the latest state of the dataset in Foundry.

A reindex job will be triggered whenever the backing dataset updates.